# OpenVPN working from CLI but not via NetworkManager GUI

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I have a working VPN connection via CLI:

```
sudo openvpn myconfigfile.ovpn
```

I imported the file in the Network Manager GUI and when I try to use it, it always fails but I can't find the reason why. I had a look at the logs of the NetworkManager via:

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager
```

and it gives this :

```
sept. 06 09:30:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <info>  [1504683056.7617] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75" name="name-of-connection" pid=3406 uid=1000 result="success"
sept. 06 09:30:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <info>  [1504683056.7900] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 23791
sept. 06 09:30:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <info>  [1504683056.8118] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
sept. 06 09:30:56 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jun 22 2017
sept. 06 09:30:56 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
sept. 06 09:30:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <info>  [1504683056.9251] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
sept. 06 09:30:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <info>  [1504683056.9251] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
sept. 06 09:30:57 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
sept. 06 09:30:57 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:port
sept. 06 09:30:57 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: UDP link local: (not bound)
sept. 06 09:30:57 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:port
sept. 06 09:30:57 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
sept. 06 09:30:57 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
sept. 06 09:31:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <warn>  [1504683116.7116] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
sept. 06 09:31:56 alt-machine nm-openvpn-serv[23791]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
sept. 06 09:31:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <warn>  [1504683116.7199] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
sept. 06 09:31:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <info>  [1504683116.7208] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
sept. 06 09:31:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <info>  [1504683116.7210] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

Are there other logs where I can have a look ?

Answer (score 9):

For me, the answer from spotter was the solution. He worked it out and filed a bug report.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1847144

To elaborate on the steps to solve the problem:

I am using KDE. Possibly the network manager interface is different. This is what I did.
Imported the openvpn config file into networkmanger. It makes a connection, it times out, and no amount of debugging level gives any more hint. The connection works fine from the command line.

I edit the openvpn file, and extract the key block into a file.
It is the key block in between  and 
so my text file looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
92e2de5ae643729863zzzz4a0ebe952
.
.
.

cc05zxzxczczxxczxzxczxce902b498a5
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
```

I save it as openvpn_cryptkey.key

Then

- open the openvpn connection already imported into networkmanager
- choose Advanced... on the VPM (openvpn) tab,Choose TLS Settings, and
  change only two things

Mode is TLS-Crypt

and Key File, use the path of the key file created just before.

And immediately, the connection worked

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue recently with PiVPN.  the ovpn files it creates have a tls-crypt section and network-manager doesn't extract that key and set it up in the vpn profile it creates.  Extracting it manually and setting it up manually enabled the vpn to work fine.

I filed a bug in launchpad against it for this.

Comment: what is the bug number? Is it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1847144

Comment: this should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change the log level of NetworkManager to double check what's going on in syslog:

Terminal:

```
sudo NetworkManager --log-level=DEBUG
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Try to connect VPN again over NetworkManger and look out for messages about `nm-openvpn` in syslog. In my case it was a letter space in my path to the .crt file:

```
nm-openvpn[1957]: Options error: --ca fails with '/home/user/IPVanish%20config/ca.ipvanish.com.crt': No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

So, I fixed the problem by deleting letter spaces in this path to my config files.

More:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=272916#p1510747

Reset log level back to INFO later.

Comment: Have the exact same issue, however logs didn't reveal anything more than what's displayed in INFO level, and there's no apparent issue with paths to the file ..

Answer (score 0):

Like the error output said :
`sept. 06 09:30:57 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
sept. 06 09:30:57 alt-machine nm-openvpn[23798]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
sept. 06 09:31:56 alt-machine NetworkManager[19942]: <warn>  [1504683116.7116] vpn-connection[0x55e876784720,24fc3644-b324-46a4-9ce1-c1a0fcea1b75,"name-of-connection",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.`

Probably your certificate still cannot bound the link. Try this steps. Move your `myconfigfile.ovpn` file to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and then restart your NetworkManager Service . and change your directory access of CA from `ca = /folderTo/vpn-ca.crt` to `ca = /folderTo/vpn.ovpn` .and also removed of `[ipv6] method=auto`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I moved the `ovpn` file as you suggested, but the rest didn't make sense to me. _Change your directory access of CA from x.crt to x.ovpn_ . Only `cert`, `pem`,`key`, `cer` or `p12` files are accepted for that.

Comment: @ArthurAttout did you make a password to your cert? To many variable for me, perhaps a script issue or samething else

Comment: Yes, the certificate has a password. I tried saving it for all users (unencrypted) or enter it manually each time, but neither worked. This overall issue seems to be known, I've found several obscure thread about it, but neither gave any fix

Comment: So that's not about NM GUI issue but about a script of your network. Forgive me, i can't help you about that.

Comment: What do you mean a script of my network ? The exact same configuration file works with `openvpn myfile.ovpn`

Comment: No about ovpn file but your certificate file @ArthurAttout

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Nevertheless, the issue is definitely from the Network Manager, since the OVPN profile is valid and operational.

Answer (score 0):

Import openvpn file via the cli instead of the gui

```
sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file [client].ovpn
```